# How to run Sequelize down migration for single file

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm working on a migration using Sequelize. If the migration `up` method throws an error, the migration is not logged in the database as having completed. So, if I run `db:migrate:undo`, it instead runs `down` on the previous (and working) migration. As a result, I have a half executed migration where the schema for it remains in the database because the corresponding `down` method is never run by Sequelize. So, I need to either somehow force a single `down` method to run (which I'm not seeing an option for). Or, I need to manually clean up my database every time I run a failing migration, which can be a real pain for complicated migrations where I'm constantly going through trial and error. Is there an easier way to doing this?

Answer (score 13):

```
sequelize db:migrate:undo --name 20200409091823-example_table.js
```

Use this command to undo any particular migration

Answer (score 2):

manually insert the migration into your migrations table so that sequelize will think it *has* completed.

To verify check the status of your migrations before and after you edit the table.

```
db:migrate:status
```

Everything listed as "up" is something that can go "down" and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it as of now... There is an open issue for this in Sequelize cli [repo](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/532)

Answer (score 0):

I tried something and it worked for me:

- rename your migration file and make sure it comes first alphabetically (make it the first one in migration files)
- comment code in the second migration file
- run `sequelize db:migrate`

This will run only the first migration file.

*Don't forget to uncomment the migration file you commented before*